# joining two queries while filtering on a dataframe

Tags: python

This is my code, where I'm trying to filter on a dataframe.

```
filter_dict = {  
    
    'Node': str(input("Enter a value for Node:      ")), input for example 12nm
    '`Issue Type`': str(input("Enter a value for Issue Type:      ")),
    '`Status`': str(input("Enter a value for Status:      ")),
    '`SR_Quarter`': str(input("Enter a value for SR_Quarter:      "))# input for example is '2020-Q4' to '2021-Q2'
               }

query = ' & '.join([f'{k} == "{v}"' for k,v in filter_dict.items() if v!=""]) #here 
sr = filter_dict['`SR_Quarter`'].replace(' to ', '<= `SR_Quarter` <=')

if sr == "":
   query
else:
   query += ' & ' + sr
    
df.query(query)
```

When I run query and sr separately, they both work, but when I'm trying to add them together it prints a df with 0 rows. Can someone please help me?